# descendent model belongs to parents models in TREE structure RAILS 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, model-view-controller, data-structures

I want to setup a work order system in a tree structure like so

[image: model diagram]

so the workorder belongs to a tenant, but also belongs to the property he/she lives in, and belongs to the landlord.

I know I can't have belongs_to :through. I want to be able to see all of the work order submitted by each tenant, and see all work order per property, and per landlord.

so if a landlord click on an work order, it will say which house it is for, and which tenant submitted this order.

So what is the best way to model this? polymorphic? or just straight up, belongs to?

Answer (score 0):

Work orders belong to tenants, properties, and landlords. A work order must have all of those set when it is created. Landlords have many properties. Properties have many tenants, tenants have many work orders.

To see all work orders submitted by a tenant just do `tenant.workorders`. To see all he work orders per property per landlord you need to get all of the landlord's properties and then get all of the work orders for each of those properties.

Comment: yea, thats what I thought. so there would be at least 3 foreign_ids on the work order model, that maps it out to the property, tenant and the landlord.I guess I'd go the routed of Materialized Path for this.